# Automatic MySQL Database backup and email through cPanel cron

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

Can anybody help how to setup a automatic backup of mysql database and then emailing it to me daily?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutoMySQLBackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) gets great reviews.  I have not used it but it seems to do exactly what you are looking for.  Also, [here](http://www.noupe.com/php/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html) is another link with different ways to backup, including emailing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to automate your MySQL database backups, say with a cron job, and you host your databases with CPanel web hosting, then there's a PHP script you can use.

You can pick it up here: http://www.hostliketoast.com/2011/10/cpanel-hosting-full-database-backup-script-free-download/

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Not need more.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Must be installed mutt on your box
mydate=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
host=$(hostname)
databases='' #'database1  database2 databaseN'

mysqldump --opt --all-databases > /tmp/$host.$mydate.sql
# if not all mysql databases mysqldump --opt $databases > /tmp/$host.$mydate.sql
gzip --best /tmp/mysql02.$mydate.sql
echo "Backup MySQL" | mutt -a /tmp/$host.$mydate.sql.gz -s "Backup MySQL $mydate" -- mail@mail.to
```